# writing code to generate permutations of a string

Tags: hashset

I am looking to generate permutations and as part of the process,I wrote the following code using HashSet.

```
public static HashSet<String> getAllPermutations(String str) 
{
   // Create a hash set to prevent any duplicate entries
   HashSet<String> permutations = new HashSet<String>();

   if(str == null || str.length() == 0) 
    {
      permutations.add("");
      return permutations;
    }

      char first = str.charAt(0);

      String remainingString = str.substring(1);

      HashSet<String> words = getAllPermutations(remainingString);
      System.out.println("here: "+ words.toString());
}
```

My question is that when I try to print out thenter code heree hashset "words" using the string `abc` in the main method, I get this output:

```
here: [] 
here: [c]
here: [bc, cb]
```

Why am I getting `bc` and `cb` both in my HashSet? Is there something about Hashsets I am missing here?

Comment: Consider improving the formatting of your question as it looks pretty chaotic

Comment: I have been doing for the past 15 minutes.Stackoverflow would not allow my original formatting actually,hence the chaos

Comment: I did that for you. Click `edit` and see how it's done and improve if I missed something